# Why can subprocess.Popen("mkdir dir", shell=True); os.chdir("./dir") fail?

Tags: python, shell

I'm using Python to automatize a series of simulations. For this, the script should create a directory,cd into this, start a simulation, copy the data from this to a different folder and then do another simulation and henceforth. But When I try to create a directory and cd into the directory I just created, I'm getting a `FileNotFoundError`, eventhough the directory is there. The sample code is given below, how can we fix this?

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen("mkdir MyFolder", shell=True)
os.chdir("./MyFolder")
sp.Popen("touch ImInMyFolder.txt", shell=True)

How can we fix this?
```

Comment: Don't use a shell, just do `os.mkdir("MyFolder")`.  The problem is that, when using `Popen`, Python does not wait for the process to finish.  The process runs in parallel with yours.

Comment: Also, your `touch` can be done as `open("InMyFolder.txt").close()`.  `subprocess` is great, but never use it when there is an equivalent Python service.